# PhpStorm code analysis: custom "interpolate" delimiters in PHP files

Tags: php, webpack, phpstorm, lodash

I am working on a WordPress theme project which uses webpack with the **copy-webpack-plugin** to copy the WordPress theme files to a `dist` folder and the lodash `template()` method to transform data properties wrapped in "interpolate" delimiters within PHP files. This is done to prefix function names with unique properties (stored in a config object) for the purpose of avoiding naming collisions.

The problem with this approach is the PhpStorm IDE does not recognize the "interpolate" delimiters as valid PHP syntax and this causes a whole lot of code analysis and formatting errors. The only way I can think of is to disable code analysis within the php files containing the delimiter syntax.

I would like to know if it is possible to allow the PhpStorm IDE to recognize these "interpolate" delimiters and their syntax and allow the IDE to ignore/understand their occurrence so that I may continue the use of code analysis and formatting.

With many thanks,

**functions.php example**

```
 // theme.slug wrapped in interpolate delimiters // not valid php syntax

 function <%= theme.slug %>_foo(){  
   echo "bar";
}
```

**Webpack config**

```js
   const config = {
     paths: {...},
     outputs: {...},
     theme: {
       slug: 'foobar',
     }
   }

   module.exports = {

   plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            context: config.paths.theme,
            from: '**/*',
            transform: (content) => template(content)(config),
            to: config.outputs.dist
          }
        ],
      }
    ),
  ]

}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. The very best I may suggest to try is to somehow try to use a TextMate bundle for PHP files (e.g. by having separate file extension, not a standard `.php`) where IDE will provide only basic syntax colors and therefore will not complain on unexpected extra/higher level templating language tags as it will not parse/validate the actual PHP code). Other than that: give it different (not PHP extension) and treat it as plain text or whatever where IDE will not complain on wrong PHP syntax (but you will not have any code completion for PHP)

Comment: Another possible alternative .. is to not to use templating but to use some unique prefix (e.g. `XXprefixXX`) which you then replace using plain string `replace` functionality (`function XXprefixXX_foo()` --> `function foobar_foo()`). Obviously, you would need to use some different webpack plugin for that and perhaps some manual config for such replacement pairs...

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much for your help. Since code completion is a requirement, using unique prefixes/delimiters should do the trick. The lodash `.template()` method does have the ability to use custom template delimiters via assigning a pattern to the `.templateSettings` property. Thank you again.